# Uploading file with a unique name - what's wrong with my code?

Tags: php

I'm trying to upload a file to the server using this code:

```
$data = substr($_POST['imageData'], strpos($_POST['imageData'], ",") + 1);
$decodedData = base64_decode($data);
$name = uniqid(rand(), true) . '.jpg';
$fp = fopen('"imgdownload/'.$name.'"', 'wb');
fwrite($fp, $decodedData);
fclose($fp);
```

The file doesn't upload this way, it only works if I put a default name like

```
$fp = fopen("imgdownload/myfile", 'wb');
```

I get this response:

**Warning**:  fopen("imgdownload/1892454042e0263cf14.94958715.jpg"): failed to open stream: Invalid argument in **C:\xampp\htdocs\OrlenOla\api\process.php** on line **6**

**Warning**:  fwrite() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\OrlenOla\api\process.php** on line **7**

**Warning**:  fclose() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in **C:\xampp\htdocs\OrlenOla\api\process.php** on line **8**

I'm looking through the code over and over and I don't see what the problem might be. Anybody help?

Answer (score 4):

As errors saying:

> Warning: fopen("imgdownload/1892454042e0263cf14.94958715.jpg"): failed
>   to open stream: Invalid argument in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\OrlenOla\api\process.php on line 6

You have "nested" quotes in filename.

```
$fp = fopen('"imgdownload/' . $name . '"', 'wb');
//           ^                         ^
//         nested quotes should not be here
```

Try this one:

```
$fp = fopen('imgdownload/' . $name, 'wb');
```

Comment: Yes, that's it, thank you! I'll accept when the option gets available (12 minutes).